# SPI problem in STM32 with defining new CS line. SPL F107

Tags: stm32

In my project, I connected two MCUs to each other (MISO->MISO, MOSI->MOSI, SCK->SCK). I define a new pin as the CS pin (PORTC.10). But in my receiver the sequence is wrong. Here is my code( For example I send 1234 but I get something else, sometimes works many times doesn't)

```
void SPI1_IRQHandler(void){
    unsigned long Input;
    if (SPI_I2S_GetITStatus(SPI1,SPI_I2S_IT_RXNE)== SET)
    {
        Input=SPI_I2S_ReceiveData(SPI1);
        MSG[Position]=Input;Position=Position+1;
        if (Position>=(PosMax+1))
        {
            Position=0;
            SPI_I2S_ITConfig(SPI1,SPI_I2S_IT_RXNE,DISABLE);
        }
    }
    if (SPI_I2S_GetITStatus(SPI1, SPI_I2S_IT_TXE)== SET )
    {
        SPI_I2S_ITConfig(SPI1, SPI_I2S_IT_TXE, DISABLE);
    }
}

void EXTI15_10_IRQHandler(void){
    if (EXTI_GetITStatus(EXTI_Line10) != RESET)
    {
        if (GPIO_ReadInputDataBit(GPIOC,GPIO_Pin_10)==0)
        {
            SPI_I2S_ITConfig(SPI1,SPI_I2S_IT_RXNE,ENABLE);
        }
        else
        {
            SPI_I2S_ITConfig(SPI1,SPI_I2S_IT_RXNE,DISABLE);
            if (Position>=PosMax)
            {
                Position=0;
                SendTest=MSG[2];
            }
        }
        EXTI_ClearITPendingBit(EXTI_Line10);
    }
}
```

In transmitter before sending the 10 bytes it makes the PORTC.10 low and after 1us start sending each byte. After sending 10bytes it makes PORTC.10 high again.

Comment: You need to put a scope on the SPI signals and make sure they are all behaving as you expect. You should also delete the excess white space in your code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I have checked all of them and they work fine on my oscilloscope.

Comment: If you receive invalid data (rather no data at all or constantly `0xff`), chances are that they do not agree on the SPI mode or one of them is so slow that it looks like a different SPI mode for it.

Comment: What speed do you use for the SPI bus and what's the clock speed of your MCU? Likely, your MCU is too slow for entering, executing and exiting an interrupt handler for each byte.

Comment: Thank you, I have checked the speed of two SPI and both of them are the same. Actually my problem is my receiver loses the start and stop position of input package. I need to know what my mistake is. it means I received data correctly but the receiver fill the MSG array badly.